# How do I integrate thirdparty Python Dependencies?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to make my package have a dependency on a Python package called pymorph.  Is there a supported way to require a dependency like this?

Thanks,
Bradley Powers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10485/how-do-i-integrate-thirdparty-python-dependencies?/) by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 422 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could either wrap the source for pymorph in a ROS package, or you could write a script in the rosdep.yaml that downloads and installs Pymorph. You can see rosdep.yaml examples here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep/rosdep.yaml#Examples

If you use the rosdep solution, please see the first two tutorials on the rosdep page:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

They will walk you through adding a rosdep dependency and declaring support for it in your OS.  NOTE: rosdep dependencies should be ones that are easily available via package managers like apt and macports.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-07-05**:
Thank you for updating the answer!

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-07-05**:
Can you make this comment an answer so that I can mark it as answered?  Thank you!

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-07-05**:
You could either wrap the source for pymorph in a ROS package, or you could write a script in the rosdep.yaml that downloads and installs Pymorph.  You can see rosdep.yaml examples here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep/rosdep.yaml#Examples

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-07-05**:
So, I certainly know how to add a regular dependency in the manifest.xml file, but the issue is that pymorph isn't available via apt...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add the dependency like this

```
<rosdep name="pymorph"/>
```

in the `manifest.xml` file of the package.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1